# gzip decompression issue on OSX with TIdHTTP and TIdCompressorZLib

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm trying to fetch a page with gzip compression enabled, using `TIdHTTP` and `TIdCompressorZLib`.
On Windows, the code works fine and the data is decompressed. But the exact same code on OSX is returning garbage data that looks like its still compressed. I can't really see where it's going wrong?

This is the code I'm testing with:

```
with TIdHTTP.Create(nil) do begin
  HandleRedirects := true;
  Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(nil);
  Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
  Data := Get('http://google.com.au');
  Compressor.Free;
  Free;
  WriteLn(Data);
end;
```

`Data` looks like the original compressed garbage on OSX, while it is plain decompressed HTML on Windows.

I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 1 and OSX 10.11.

Answer (score 1):

You are *manually* setting the `TIdHTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding` property to tell the webserver that it is OK to send a compressed response **even if `TIdCompressorZLib` is not actually ready to handle it**.  In your case, the `TIdCompressorZLib.IsReady` property is likely reporting False on OSX, but True on Windows.

In January 2016, Indy was updated to dynamically load the ZLib library on-demand the first time ZLib is used (SVN rev 5330).  That change broke `TIdCompressorZLib`, which was later fixed in February 2016 (SVN rev 5343).  I do not know if that fix is in Berlin or not.  Try installing the latest SVN rev and see if the problem continues ([instructions](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.aspx) and [download](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.aspx)).

When using the `TIdHTTP.Compressor` property, **DO NOT** set the `Request.AcceptEncoding` property manually at all:

```
with TIdHTTP.Create(nil) do begin
  HandleRedirects := true;
  Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(nil);
  // Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate'; // <-- here
  Data := Get('http://google.com.au');
  Compressor.Free;
  Free;
  WriteLn(Data);
end;
```

Leave `Request.AcceptEncoding` blank, and let `TIdHTTP` update it internally if the assigned `Compressor` is actually ready to handle compressed responses.

---

BTW, you are leaking the `TIdHTTP` and `TIdCompressorZLib` objects if `TIdHTTP.Get()` raises an exception on failure.  You should be using `try/finally` blocks:

```
with TIdHTTP.Create(nil) do
try
  HandleRedirects := true;
  Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(nil);
  try
    // Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
    Data := Get('http://google.com.au');
  finally
    Compressor.Free;
  end;
finally
  Free;
end;
WriteLn(Data);
```

Comment: Thanks. You are correct that the `IsReady` property was returning false. It constantly returns false after several http requests, as it appears the zlib library is not being loaded at all, which I presume is the bug introduced in Jan-2016 SVN rev 5330. I added the `IdZlibHeaders` unit to the Uses list, and called `IdZlibHeaders.Load` after creating the `TIdCompressorZLib` object, and now `IsReady` is returning true and gzip content is being decompressed

Comment: Yes, the original bug was that `TIdCompressorZLib` expected `IdZLibHeaders.Load()` to have already been called, so `IsReady` simply returned the value from `IdZLibHeaders.Loaded()`.  The fix was to make `IsReady` call `Load()` instead, in case it hadn't been called yet.

Comment: Nick C workaround also fixed it for me on 10.1 Berlin.